# using sed to delete lines with multiple matching strings in a single line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, centos7

I have a file containing multiple lines. Each line has a specific set of keywords or pattern in it. These keywords remain same for all lines. I want to use sed to delete matching lines from a file based on a multiple keywords. So for instance the line in the file will look something like

```
Begin: Action Title:<could be anything> --Date:<somedate> Value1:<could be anything> Value2:<could be anything>
```

The file has other irrelavant content as well. How can I use sed to locate the matching lines based on multiple patterns such as **Begin: Action**,  **Title:** as well as **Date:** or **Value1**. I can use a single pattern/keyword to identify the matching lines but to be safe I want to use all the keywords/patterns in a line to make sure I do not delete the other lines.

So i am doing

```
sed -n '/Begin: Action/,/Date:/,/Value1:/d' File
```

But its not working.

Comment: What you are doing will print nothing since you are using `-n`. Without that though you can group multiple condition using code blocks, `'/Begin: Action/{/Date:/{/Value1:/d}}'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed the -n switch and the console lists the lines that do not match. The /d switch should do an inplace deletion of the matching lines?, however viewing the files shows that none of the matching line was removed.

Comment: fixed it, i was mising --in-place switch